# Snap group box to contained controls when resizing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, groupbox

When resizing the group box, is there a way to snap it to the bounds of the controls it contains?

Currently, resizing it snaps only relative to controls outside the group box or if Alt is pressed, it doesn't snap to anything. I tried using Shift or Control while resizing, but the snap guides do not recognize the contained controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the AutoSize property to True so it is automatic.  Tweak the Padding property if necessary to adjust the gap between the control and the box edge.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Would there be a way to do the same with the entire form? If I enable AutoSize for the main form, it doesn't seem to snap to the controls it contains. (Seems I can only award the bounty after 23 hours have passed, so I will check it then.)